Algebraic Extension with infinitely many generators
Let $K / F$ be a field extension, $A \subset K$ a set in which all the elements are algebraic over $F$. I wonder what the elements in $F(A)$ look like, where $F(A)$ means the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F \cup A$.
When $A = \{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m \}$ is finite, we may find an $F$-basis for $F( \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m )$. One way is as follows: define $F_0 := F$, and $F_{i + 1} := F_i (\alpha_{i + 1})$ for each $0 \le i < m$. Then
$$
F = F_0 \subset F_1 \subset \cdots \subset F_m = F(A).
$$
Since $\alpha_{i + 1}$ is algebraic over $F$, it is evidently algebraic over $F_i$. Let $d_{i + 1} := \deg_{F_i} (\alpha_{i + 1})$. Then:
$$
F_{m} 
= 
\bigoplus_{i_m = 0}^{d_m - 1} F_{m - 1} \alpha_m^{i_m}
=
\bigoplus_{i_m = 0}^{d_m - 1} \cdots \bigoplus_{i_1 = 0}^{d_1 - 1} F \alpha_{1}^{i_1} \cdots \alpha_m^{i_m}
=
\bigoplus_{i \in I} F \alpha^i,
$$
where $I := \{ i \in \mathbb{Z}^m \mid 0 \le i_k < d_k \}$. Henceforce, $\{ \alpha^i \mid i \in I \}$ is an $F$-basis of $F(A)$.
When $A$ is infinite, I wonder if we can find an $F$-basis for $F(A)$ or find some way to describe the elements in $F(A)$. I tried to use Zermelo well ordering principle to make $A$ into a well ordered set and use the previous trick but fails.

There is a Galois theory for infinite dimension that is substantially different from when the extension to be studied is finite

Frankly, I don't think there's much point in trying to find a basis for an infinite algebraic extension. Already in the finite case you have to make a non-canonical choice of what order to consider the $\alpha_i$ in, and in the infinite case it gets much worse. I've never seen anyone write down a basis of, say, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ or even $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, nor is there any need for such a thing. It breaks the Galois symmetry!
A different type of description is produced by infinite Galois theory, which retains Galois symmetry. The normal basis theorem admits the following generalization, which is apparently due to Lenstra (from 1985, which seems shockingly recent to me):

Theorem: Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, possibly infinite, with Galois group $G$. Then $L$, as a $G$-module, is isomorphic to the space of continuous functions $G \to K$, where $G$ has its profinite topology.

This description does not furnish a basis of $L$ in the infinite case but arguably it's even better; this tells us precisely how the Galois group $G$ acts on $L$. To me this is a very non-obvious and interesting statement already for the case of the algebraic closure $L = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of a finite field; it says that $L$, as a module over the absolute Galois group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p)$, is isomorphic to the vector space of periodic sequences $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}_p$, with the Frobenius $F$ acting by a shift. You can check, for example, that the number of fixed points of $F^n$ is $p^n$, the size of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ as expected; this isomorphism identifies $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ with the vector space of sequences with period (dividing) $n$, which correctly describes the Frobenius action on $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ also (this is just the usual normal basis theorem for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$). We also get a vivid picture of the inclusion relationships among the finite fields, the degree of the minimal polynomial, etc. It's very nice! And this generalizes to any infinite Galois extension.

Thank your for taking time to write. As a beginner of Galois theory, I think that it is quite inspiring and of great help. Thank you so much!

Partially order sets via set inclusion.  You can use Zorn's Lemma to prove that (in this partial order) there is a maximal "algebraically independent" subset $B \subseteq F(A)$.  It's not hard to see (via maximality) that $B$ is an $F$-basis for $F(A)$.
This is pretty much the same proof that shows every vector space has a basis.
